# Compute file content hash with Scala

Tags: scala, file, hash, playframework

In our app, we are in need to compute file hash, so we can compare if the file was updated later.
The way I am doing it right now is with this little method:

```
protected[services] def computeMigrationHash(toVersion: Int): String = {
    val migrationClassName = MigrationClassNameFormat.format(toVersion, toVersion)
    val migrationClass = Class.forName(migrationClassName)
    val fileName = migrationClass.getName.replace('.', '/') + ".class"
    val resource = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(fileName)

    logger.debug("Migration file - " + resource.getFile)

    val file = new File(resource.getFile)
    val hc = Files.hash(file, Hashing.md5())

    logger.debug("Calculated migration file hash - " + hc.toString)

    hc.toString
  }
```

It all works perfectly, until the code get's deployed into different environment and file file is located in a different absolute path. I guess, the hashing take the path into account as well. 
What is the best way to calculate some sort of reliable hash of a file content that well produce the same result for as log as the content of a file stays the same?

Thanks,

Comment: Which `Files` implementation?  The google and nio do not have `Files.hash` in them. I'd like to look at the source code.

Comment: @javadba I think it's from guava: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#hash%28java.io.File,%20com.google.common.hash.HashFunction%29

Comment: @javadba its `com.google.common.io.Files`

Comment: thx - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Having perused the source code https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/Files.java  - *only* the file contents are hashed - the *path* does not come into play.

```
 public static HashCode hash(File file, HashFunction hashFunction) throws IOException {
    return asByteSource(file).hash(hashFunction);
  }
```

Therefore you need not worry about locality of the file. Now *why* you end up with a different hash on a different fs .. maybe you should compare the size/contents  to ensure eg no compound eol's were introduced.